# Access runtime parameters in AWS Glue Studio

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-connection, aws-glue3.0

I have created a Glue job using Glue studio Visual Editor. This job is getting data from a JDBC data source (Clickhouse Database) using a query. Doing some business transformations and then storing the data back to the database table using the same JDBC connection. In the source I want to parametrized the sql query so that I can change the dates with each run. I have defined the job parameters in the job details.  Can any one help me how to access these params. As per the business requirement I have to develop the job using visual editor for easy maintenance purpose later on.

[Job Params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmWbw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible by just using the UI currently.

If you can edit the code, you can use the [getResolvedOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-get-resolved-options.html) function.

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["enddate"])

print(args["enddate"])
```

Comment: Like I have mentioned in my question I have developed the job using Visual editor. If I had chosen script mode, I would have used this function. Is it possible to access params if the job has been developed in visual mode.

Comment: The only option I found to write scripting lines is by using custom transform. My understanding is we can't use that functionality for this purpose

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible currently. Updated my answer accordingly.